# WinDBG show incomplete stack

Tags: stack, windbg, crash-dumps, postmortem-debugging

I got a complicated crash dump: a (32 bit) program (C++) was written in Visual Studio 6 and executed on an 64 Bit machine. So, I got a 64 bit crash dump.
Sadly, I havn't access to VS 6 (and I don't think VS6 can handle 64 bit). VS 2015 can not open this crash dump (32 Bit debugger can not debug 64 bit..), so I tried it with WinDBG (and my own dmp file viewer :).

Viewing the stack only shows only system addresses (0x7..).

Eg.:

```
 .  0  Id: bdc.b40 Suspend: 0 Teb: 00000000`7efdb000 Unfrozen
        Start: XXXX+0x4bf33d (00000000`008bf33d)
        Priority: 2  Priority class: 128  Affinity: f
   # Child-SP          RetAddr           Call Site
  00 00000000`0008e2e8 00000000`73deaedc wow64win!NtUserGetMessage+0xa
  01 00000000`0008e2f0 00000000`73e3d18f wow64win!whNtUserGetMessage+0x30
  02 00000000`0008e350 00000000`73dc2776 wow64!Wow64SystemServiceEx+0xd7
  03 00000000`0008ec10 00000000`73e3d286 wow64cpu!ServiceNoTurbo+0x2d
  04 00000000`0008ecd0 00000000`73e3c69e wow64!RunCpuSimulation+0xa
  05 00000000`0008ed20 00000000`77c7fb96 wow64!Wow64LdrpInitialize+0x42a
  06 00000000`0008f270 00000000`77cdbd09 ntdll!LdrpInitializeProcess+0x17e3
  07 00000000`0008f760 00000000`77c6a36e ntdll! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+0x22a30
  08 00000000`0008f7d0 00000000`00000000 ntdll!LdrInitializeThunk+0xe
```

There isn't even the entry point as listed above, in ThreadInfoListStream or

```
0:000> ~*
.  0  Id: bdc.b40 Suspend: 0 Teb: 00000000`7efdb000 Unfrozen
      Start: XXXX+0x4bf33d (00000000`008bf33d)
      Priority: 2  Priority class: 128  Affinity: f
[..]
```

What is wrong / where I'm wrong? What can I do to see the whole stack? Is there anywhere a help / guide how to unwind the Stack on my own (I'm able to load / read pdbs, I have access to the memory saved in the dump, I've already unencoded the main part of the TEB, ...).

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.effmach` command can be used to switch between architectures. It takes `x86` or `amd64` as an argument.

You can also load the `wow64exts` extension. It has a `!sw` command that toggles between the two modes.

Note how the command prompt and the output of `k` changes:

```
0:000> k
Child-SP          RetAddr           Call Site
00000000`006ee8e8 00000000`60db21ef wow64cpu!CpupSyscallStub+0xc
00000000`006ee8f0 00000000`60e5bfa1 wow64cpu!Thunk0Arg+0x5
00000000`006ee9a0 00000000`60e4cbb0 wow64!RunCpuSimulation+0xf311
00000000`006eea20 00007ff9`0bef2a11 wow64!Wow64LdrpInitialize+0x120
00000000`006eecd0 00007ff9`0bf289c6 ntdll!EtwEventProviderEnabled+0x1cb1
00000000`006ef0d0 00007ff9`0bed9fae ntdll!memset+0x1c006
00000000`006ef150 00000000`00000000 ntdll!LdrInitializeThunk+0xe

0:000> .load wow64exts
0:000> !sw
Switched to 32bit mode

0:000:x86> k
ChildEBP RetAddr  
007eeebc 09ad86fe win32u!NtUserWaitMessage+0xc
WARNING: Frame IP not in any known module. Following frames may be wrong.
007eefd8 7303eaf6 0x9ad86fe
007eefe4 730470e9 clr!CallDescrWorkerInternal+0x34
007ef038 73047714 clr!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+0x6b
007ef0a0 731dac11 clr!MethodDescCallSite::CallTargetWorker+0x16a
007ef1cc 731dad09 clr!RunMain+0x1ad
```